# Finding a string with regex

Tags: regex

I'm looking to match "Serial Number:" and then store the value in a variable. So far I have this but for some reason it is not finding it.

```
set value [regexp -line {^\s*Serial Number: (.*)$} $expect_out(buffer) store]
```

This is the output, I want to match Serial Number and store the value in a variable:

```
Contents of Main Board IDPROM
    Assy, NetNet6300     
    Serial Number:                  091245076951       
    BoardRev:                       03.00         
    PCB Family Type:                Main Board    
    Options:                        0
```

Comment: After your colon you don't just have a single space so you should use `^\s+Serial Number:\s+(\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is the following:

```
^\s*Serial Number:[^\d]*(\d+)
```

Which looks to be like this in your example:

```
set value [regexp -line {^\s*Serial Number:[^\d]*(\d+)} $expect_out(buffer) store]
```

- [^\d]* means any amount of non-numbers (including none)
- (\d+) will match any non-zero amount of numbers

I also like h20000000's comment but I prefer to use the negative character class of what I'm looking to capture, either will work!

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help and explanation!